# kendo grid value from dropdownlist shows as undefined when not in edit mode

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

See example here: http://dojo.telerik.com/ihIco

I'm sure I had this working and I don't know what I changed.

When you go into edit mode and choose the first item (i.e. the blank, optionLabel item) and then click update, the grid displays "undefined".

Comment: did the dojo not work?  here is a fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mlh457/kjydqvew/)

Comment: Sorry it did - when you say the first item - your meaning the default (optional one) item? - If you want to allow a blank item - I recommend using a kendo Comb obox not a drop down. Then just disable search/filter on the combobox if you don't want it and add a place holder than than a blank item. a drop down list expects a valid option

Comment: Yes...the default/optional one.  ComboBox? Hmmm....well a combobox would allow the user to type directly into the control and I don't want that.  I am able to acheive what I want by putting a javascript snippet in the column template but it seems like a lot of work for something so simple.  Digging into the kendo code I am finding that the labelOption (in this case an object) is not being bound to the underlying datasource when the selection is made in the dropdownlist.  Instead, it is just binding the string value of "0" which is what the id is for the labelOption object.

Comment: You can disable typing in the combobox.. look at this demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ggkrustev/aTuK

Comment: Thanks! I'll consider doing it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is related to your template which expects a binding to property name on object Brand.

```
template: function()"#= Brand.name #",
```

Because your grid's data srouce does not have an item for the blank value Brand in that case will be null.

```
  dataSource:  {
                data: [
                    { Brand: {id: 1, name: "Ford"} } 
                ],
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "",
                        fields: {
                            Brand: { defaultValue: {id: 1, name: "Ford" }}
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

remove the option label in your drop down:

```
optionLabel: { id: 0, name: "" },
```

and force them to pick a value

Comment: yeah, forcing them to pick value would be easiest for me but having the row start out as blank helps the users see that there is a blank value that they need to provide an answer for...that's the whole purpose of the optionLabel.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Any luck figuring out the issue with the option label in place? Please share it as an answer if you have figured it out.

Comment: Appending a dummy value in the dropdown if its datasource is empty and disabling it could be one option/workaround but is not a perfect solution. If you figured it out any other way then please share.